# Error when compiling for device but not simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode

I get the following error when compiling my project for the device, but not the simulator:
**error: objc/objc-class.h: No such file or directory**

One of the files i have imports objc/objc-class.h and this is where it chokes.

Base SDK is iPhone OS 4.0 and deployment target is OS 3.2

Thanks

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
```

instead of

```
#import <objc/objc-class.h>
```

This worked for me, both for simulator & device.

Comment: Thank you. That was all it took.

Comment: There is any explanation for this? An edit would be welcome.

Comment: @FelipeCesarAssis explanation added for this answer, please gave a proper review to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

On iOS it's

`#import <objc/runtime.h>`

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't that be:

```
#import <objc/objc.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different include paths in your debug and release build settings?

If you don't want to play with the include paths, then adding the objc-class.h file to your project will also allow Xcode to find it.

Comment: Manually added the objc-class.h file and it compiles now.  I dont understand why it would work before for the simulator and not the device.  All the include paths are the same for both.